# Want to get GPS coordinates in c# codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, geolocation, gps

I'm having a bit of a problem with GPS coordinates. I'm able to get coordinates in asp.net / javascript using the geolocation, but need these to be available to a method in the c# codebehind. Unfortunately, for some reason the retrieved coordinates aren't, even if I put them into labels (they never end up there for some reason).

So, what I'm thinking now is to try and get the coordinates (just need the latitude and longitude) directly into c# somehow, even if I have to run some javascript through c# (unsure how you do that).

Does anyone have any ideas? I've posted the javascript below:

```
<button id="btnLocate" runat="server" onclick="GetLocation()" style="width: 15%">Loc</button>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function GetLocation()
            {
                if (navigator.geolocation)
                {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(ShowPosition, ShowError, { maximumAge: 5000, timeout: 10000 });
                }
                else { alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser."); }
            }
            function ShowPosition(position)
            {
                var latdata = position.coords.latitude;
                var londata = position.coords.longitude;
                document.getElementById("lblLat").value = latdata;
                document.getElementById("lblLon").value = londata;
            }
            function ShowError(error)
            {
                if (error.code == 1)
                {
                    alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
                }
                else if (error.code == 2)
                {
                    alert("Location information is unavailable.");
                }
                else if (error.code == 3)
                {
                    alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("An unknown error occurred.");
                }
            }

        </script>
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX, or put them in form elements that the browser will send back to the server,

Comment: Never tried AJAX before. As I say, I've tried putting them in labels (well, textboxes, but I've tried labels). Nor form elements. How would I do this?

Comment: Labels are not posted back.  Textboxes are, but you need to use the `ClientID`.  Look in the browser error console.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use the coordinates in an codebehind method?

Why not just run the when you open the page, and then when you click your button, you retrieve data fra labels/textboxes?

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="getCord">

if(typeof navigator.geolocation === 'undefined')
{
    alert("Geolocation services are not supported by your web browser");
}

else
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handleLocation, handleError);
}

function handleLocation(position)
{

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;

    document.getElementById('<%= latTextBox.ClientID %>').value = lat;

    var lon = position.coords.longitude;

    document.getElementById('<%= lonTextBox.ClientID %>').value = lon;

}

function handleError(error)
{
    switch (error.code) 
    {
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            alert('Timeout');
        break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            alert('Position unavailable');
        break;
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            alert('Permission denied');
        break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            alert('Unknown error');
        break;
    }
}
```

This will run without pressing an button, and your textboxes with ID latTextBox on lonTextBox will get coordinates which you can use.